# Oracle: Cannot Order by with to_CHAR column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

An application developer asked me to modify a query and order a tour DESC by year based on the created_date column since the created date is in DateTime format I tried creating a view to converting the date as a column that shows the YEAR of the tour and it looks like this:

VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW vw.v_tour_year AS
SELECT to_char(created_date,'YYYY') "tour_year", tour_id, tour_name
FROM vw.tour
```

Here is the QUERY from a Package body that needs I updated:

```
SELECT tu.*
      FROM (
        SELECT t.tour_id, t.tour_name
        FROM vw.tour t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 'x'
          FROM vw.tour_locale l
          WHERE l.culture_id = 1
          AND l.tour_name IS NOT NULL
          AND t.tour_id = l.tour_id
        )     
        UNION
        SELECT l.tour_id, l.tour_name
        FROM vw.tour_locale l
        WHERE l.culture_id = 1
        AND l.tour_name IS NOT NULL
      ) tu, vw.v_tour_year vt
     WHERE tu.tour_id = vt.tour_id
     ORDER BY vt.tour_year desc, tu.tour_name asc;
```

However, Oracle complains that vt.tour_year is an invalid identifier which I think Oracle is not allowing me to. Is this possible? or I can just only order it by the created_date?

Comment: SELECT tu.*, vt.tour_year
      FROM (
        SELECT t.tour_id, t.tour_name
        FROM vw.tour t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 'x'
          FROM vw.tour_locale l
          WHERE l.culture_id = 1
          AND l.tour_name IS NOT NULL
          AND t.tour_id = l.tour_id
        )     
        UNION
        SELECT l.tour_id, l.tour_name
        FROM vw.tour_locale l
        WHERE l.culture_id = 1
        AND l.tour_name IS NOT NULL
      ) tu, vw.v_tour_year vt
     WHERE tu.tour_id = vt.tour_id
     ORDER BY tour_year desc, tu.tour_name asc;
can you try this?

Comment: @Niraj still getting the same issue invalid identifier

Comment: I think its due to view defination. 

CREATE VIEW vw.v_tour_year AS
SELECT to_char(created_date,'YYYY') as tour_year, tour_id, tour_name
FROM vw.tour

can you create view again and try the query i posted in previous comment.

Comment: @Drew: Did you get any errors/warnings while creating the view?

Comment: Why would you use ORDER BY in CREATE VIEW at all? Create it without it, and let users - who use that view - decide sort order.

Comment: @toddlermenot No i didnt have any errors

Comment: @Littlefoot i didnt create this it was just passed to me and a developer asked me to revise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query doesn't include any columns from `vt`.  Personally, I think that is strange, to be sorting by something not in the `select`.

A view seems totally unnecessary.  Think about writing the query as:

```
SELECT tu.*,
       vt.created_date,
       to_char(vt.created_date, 'YYYY') as tour_year
FROM ((SELECT t.tour_id, t.tour_name
       FROM vw.tour t
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                         FROM vw.tour_locale l
                         WHERE l.culture_id = 1 AND
                               l.tour_name IS NOT NULL AND
                               t.tour_id = l.tour_id
                        )     
      ) UNION
      (SELECT l.tour_id, l.tour_name
       FROM vw.tour_locale l
       WHERE l.culture_id = 1 AND
             l.tour_name IS NOT NULL
      )
     ) tu JOIN
     vw.tour vt
     ON tu.tour_id = vt.tour_id
ORDER BY to_char(vt.created_date, 'YYYY') desc, tu.tour_name asc;
```

(Of course, the additional columns in the `SELECT` are optional.)

Note that this also uses proper, standard, **explicit** `JOIN` syntax.  Implicit joins using commas have been discouraged for decades.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

There's an Issue because of this

```
SELECT to_char(created_date,'YYYY') "tour_year"
```

You have double quoted the alias for a view column. In Oracle, object names are all stored capitalised regardless of the case of the expression that defined it, unless you have enclosed them with double quotes.You have 2 options basically.

1. Remove the quotes from "tour_year" in view definition and replace the view
2. If you indeed want the tour_year in lower case, you could do `ORDER BY vt."tour_year"`.

I would definitely recommend the first option.

Another important point is that you should make it a habit of using **ANSI JOIN** syntax below instead of  old `a,b` syntax for joins.

```
tu JOIN vw.v_tour_year vt
     ON ( tu.tour_id = vt.tour_id )
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, both join syntaxes are ANSI joins. The ANSI 92 SQL standards introduced the explicit join syntax (`t1 join t2 on`) and deprecated the implicit join syntax (`t1, t2 where`) .

Comment: The syntax doesn't require brackets around the `ON` clause.